Finding Value of the Infinite Product $ \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{ e^\frac{1}{n}}{1+\frac{1}{n}}$
How I can find the value of the Infinite Product $$ \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{ e^\frac{1}{n}}{1+\frac{1}{n}}$$
I tried like this :
$p_n =\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{ e^\frac{1}{k}}{1+\frac{1}{k}}= \prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{k+1}.e^\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{2}.\frac{2}{3}.\frac{3}{4}.....\frac{n}{n+1}.e^{\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}}= \frac{1}{n+1}.e^{\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}} $
but I can't find its limit

Hint: use the asymptotics $\sum_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{k}}  = \log n + \gamma  + o(1)$. For $\gamma$, see here.

@Gary I got it. thank you very much

Consider $$\frac{1}{\Gamma(z)}=ze^\gamma \prod_{n\geq 1}(1+\frac{z}{n})e^{-\frac{z}{n}}.$$
Evaluating at $z=1$ yields: $$\frac{1}{\Gamma(1)}=e^\gamma\prod_{n\geq 1}(1+\frac{1}{n})e^{-\frac{1}{n}}\Rightarrow \Gamma(1)=e^{-\gamma}\prod_{n\geq 1}\frac{e^\frac{1}{n}}{1+\frac{1}{n}}\\\Rightarrow \prod_{n\geq 1}\frac{e^\frac{1}{n}}{1+\frac{1}{n}}=e^\gamma$$
